# Erro ao mudar de servidor de hospedagem - Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Ao mudar de servidor de hospedagem, a aplicação apresenta o seguinte erro.

> session_start(): open(/var/lib/php-cgi/session/sess_bd836c00fd2e50a6ad60859449d28a85, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode escrever nesse diretório? Ele existe? Experimente alterar o local onde a sua sessão está a ser guardada [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

Comment: Já tentou utilizar as funções de sessão do próprio Laravel ao invés das nativas do PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente atualizar o composer

```
php composer update
```

Outra coisa, dê permissões a sua pasta de "cache"

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache
```